# does keeping kafka consumer poll to MAX_VALUE delay the group rebalance?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

consumer.poll(Long.MAX_VALUE);

This is to allow the processing (high latency) to complete. Are there any side effects for keeping this high value?

Does it block other messages in the partition being read? Does it adversely affect rebalancing?

Comment: It does affect rebalancing.
"higher value may delay a group rebalance since the consumer will only join the rebalance inside the call to poll."

https://javadoc.io/doc/org.apache.kafka/kafka-clients/latest/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html

Comment: You are right. `max.poll.interval.ms` affects the rebalancing, which is what  I said.

Comment: lets say the value is 8 hours, this means that the rebalancing can be delayed upto 8 hours. During this time none of the messages are processed?

1. Messages in the same partition
2. Messages in the other partitions

Comment: Yes for the second config, it would be delayed up to 8 hours. But if your consumer starts getting the message again to consume then it would be processed. If it does not get within 8 hours then the rebalancing would trigger.
for the timeout config, it would wait for 8 hours. if it does not get the message till then than an empty record set would be returned.

Comment: So this means that none of the messages even in other partitions cannot be read/processed for this duration of 8 hours (worst case scenario)?

Comment: Each consumer behaves **independently** in the consumer group. Whatever configs we apply to the consumer will be only applicable to that single consumer only. It might so happen that you are able to consume from other partitions. And only one partition is impacted. If your producer stops producing the message altogether, then whatever you say completely makes sense. So in the worst case, you are correct.

Comment: As I understand, this value (max.poll.interval.ms) must be kept as minimum (seconds/minutes range) as possible. But why does it support Long.MAX_VALUE as the maximum, is it only meant to be configured for streaming systems?

Comment: I have mentioned this in my answer. `Sometimes it is known that the message would not be available for consumption during a certain time period.` Let's say you have a system where the messages are not available in the night time and this is the nature of the application. In that case, you know for sure that consumer is not dead and you can avoid the rebalancing. Now it is completely your choice whether you want to set this to a high or low value depending on the use case.

Answer (score 3):

There are two configurations that you should understand for this.

1. **timeout** that you specify to the poll method.
2. **MAX_POLL_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG** while creating the Kafka consumer.

**1. timeout:**
From the Kafka documentation for the poll method:

> This method returns immediately if there are records available.
> Otherwise, it will **await the passed timeout**. If the timeout
> expires, an empty record set will be returned.
>
> @param timeout: The maximum time to block (must not be greater than
> {@link Long#MAX_VALUE} milliseconds)

**So what if I keep this value higher?**

Each iteration of the poll method would wait for this higher value that you set if the records are not available to be consumed.

**Does it adversely affect rebalancing?**

**No,** this config does not have a relation to the rebalancing that gets triggered if the consumer in the group is found to be dead by the Kafka consumer group management.

**2. MAX_POLL_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG**

From the Kafka documentation for this config

> The maximum delay between invocations of poll() when using consumer
> group management. This places an **upper bound on the amount of time
> that the consumer can be idle before fetching more records.** If poll()
> is not called before expiration of this timeout, then the consumer is
> considered failed and the group will rebalance in order to reassign
> the partitions to another member.

**So what if I keep this value higher?**

Sometimes it is known that the message would not be available for consumption during a certain time period. And this is the nature of the application, the producer of the topic might not produce messages in a certain time period.

In that case, we want to stop polling from Kafka. We Know that **poll is stopped intentionally and the consumer is not failed.** Setting this to a high value like 8 hours will ensure that re-balance simply does not happen.

**Does it adversely affect rebalancing?**

**Yes,** this config decides when the rebalancing would be triggered. If you set this to high value, rebalancing would be postponed until that amount of time.